# Asp.net Core Odata on Mongodb like filter

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, odata

I have a Asp.net Core 2.2 Odata Controller where I need to filter the name of persons with the "like" functionality. This errors out.  Is this query support by MongoDB driver (ver 2.8.1) ?

http://192.168.1.151:5000/v2/odata/users?$filter=contains(Name, 'Smith')&$top=1&$count=true

If I I use exact or eq filter it works

http://192.168.1.151:5000/v2/odata/users?$filter=Name eq 'Smith Alan')&$top=1&$count=true

```
[10:30:17.208  ERR][0HLO4RQ58RQQ9:00000001] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: IIF((({document}{name} == null) OrElse False), null, Convert({document}{name}.Contains("Loi"), Nullable`1)) is not supported.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateWhere(WhereExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateOrderBy(OrderByExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateTake(TakeExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateTake(TakeExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslatePipeline(PipelineExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, ExpressionTranslationOptions translationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Execute(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.TruncatedCollection`1..ctor(IQueryable`1 source, Int32 pageSize)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults[T](IQueryable`1 queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults(IQueryable queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Func`2 modelFunction, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func`2 createQueryOptionFunction)
```

Answer (score 3):

The fix for the problem is to add `HandleNullPropagation` to false.

```
 [EnableQuery( HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False)]
 public IActionResult Get()
 {
      return Ok(_db.MyMongoDataCollection().AsQueryable());
 }
```